# How long can dimethyl sulfoxide be safely stored in a HDPE "barrier bottle"?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solvents, plastics, chemical-engineering

How long can dimethyl sulfoxide be contained in a HDPE barrier bottle without any reaction between the plastic and the solvent?  I have read that DMSO is not reactive with HDPE, but I would like to know if anyone has alternative data.  I received a shipment of 99.999% pure DMSO, directly from the manufacturer, in specially made HDPE gallon jugs, but I am wondering if I would be well advised to transfer it to glass containers for long-term storage, to maintain purity.  Thank you for any insights!

edit: Someone in the comments has suggested I add this information: the intended use of this DMSO is for personal experimentation and research regarding the pain reducing qualities of DMSO, utilizing myself as the test subject.

Comment: I am interested to know if anyone who uses DMSO for research, ie someone who might have the equipment to test whether a solvent has leached something from a plastic container, has ever noticed DMSO being contaminated after storage in HDPE.  People who use DMSO for medical reasons generally have no such equipment and have to rely on trusting the manufacturer.  Just looking for data from people who might know!  I don't think the intended usage here matters, plus it is common for people to divert the attention to whether or not one should use said treatment, rather than answer the question.

Comment: There is another aspect, uncontrolled exposure to contamination because of liquid transfer. E.g., but not limited to, presence of sulfur in molecule may support extraction of trace heavy metals from glass. There is general stereotype plastics=bad, glass=good. Sometimes, it is the opposite.

Comment: Just wondering, why did this question get a minus one?  What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

2 years according to the Aldrich data sheet
https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/deepweb/assets/sigmaaldrich/product/documents/303/292/d8779pis.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Almost indefinitely as long as the temperature is below 60 degrees or so. I have seen vats full of DMSO of Poly propylene FRP construction up for years. Although the one we used is 99.1% and more and not 99.999% but yeah one FRP tank is more than 22 years old and has been filled with DMSO all its like used to make TMSO-B all day everyday.

Comment: Thank you!  This is helpful, the kind of answer I am looking for.  My storage area can get up to 80 degrees F.  Should I go ahead and transfer the DMSO from the HDPE bottles into amber glass?  The glass bottles are lead-free.

Comment: 60 degrees I meant C. Keep it in HDPE or Amber Glass don't matter. If you want to keep it even safer, just add some water. Water DMSO is even safer. DMSO doesn't attack things like Epoxy either. Its not like its NMP